# Most efficient way to align multiple objects in Unity (with or without code)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example using void Update to continuously align their positions like

```
    first.transform.position = second.transform.position;
```

Seems quite inefficient and in cases where you can't really make a child for example:
Trying to align an object with a text UI

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the object as a children to the `first` `GameObject` this way it will always move accordingly when you move the main object.

```
second.transform.SetParent(first.transform);
```

Keep in mind you will still need to center the `second` object one time upon adding it as a child.

Comment: In some cases yes but not in the example that I gave in the description, UI usually keeps the original position no matter what parent

Comment: @FirstTry UI elements can be made children and it will behave like I explained.

Answer (score 0):

For Text Elements, there are two options to make them follow a particular GameObject in the world:

1. You can create a Canvas with Render Mode set to `World Space`, like this:
   [image: Using World Space Canvas]
2. You can use the [TextMesh Pro](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/84126?aid=1100lGny) (now Free) and use it's TextMeshPro component:[image]

I rather use the second solution since you don't have to create a Canvas to fit your simple component TextMesh Pro is really great for any size of fonts since it uses [Signed Distance Field Fonts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGZRHJvJYIg).

But if you want the text always face the player camera, you have to implement a Billboard, which may have the same impact as your initial script

```
public class Billboard : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Update() { transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward; }
}
```

Actually, there is a third solution, but envolves purchasing an extension called [UnityConstraints](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/1919?aid=1100lGny), which is an excelent extension I always use and it's made for creating any type of constraints: billboards, follow, look-at, etc. But depending on your game this could be an overwhelming solution.

Answer (score 0):

Group the GameObjects that you want to align under a common GameObject and add a *Horizontal Layout Group* Component in the inspector. Use the child alignment option and spacing to align the objects the way you want.

Ref: https://needoneapp.medium.com/how-to-align-game-objects-in-unity-735f93d5b74

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but aligning objects in unity is not about positions only, its also about meshes boundaries. For example if two cubes are in the same position but there meshes have not the same size, then they will not be considered as aligned.
So you have to calculate the boundaries of the meshes of all the objects to be aligned.

```
private Bounds GetPrefabBounds(GameObject prefabInstance)
    {

        Bounds prefabBounds = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero);
        Renderer[] renderers = prefabInstance.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

        if (renderers.Length > 0)
        {
            prefabBounds = renderers[0].bounds;

            for (int i = 1; i < renderers.Length; i++)
            {
                prefabBounds.Encapsulate(renderers[i].bounds);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Prefab does not contain any Renderer components.");
        }

        return prefabBounds;
    }
```

If you don't have time for all that you can use this tool : [Align, Array and Path Tools](https://u3d.as/364X) from the unity asset store. But you have to use Unity 2022.2.19f1 or later.